# How to call method in BaseViewModel class from parent class just outside the Widget build(BuildContext context) method

Tags: flutter, dart, mvvm

I am using MVVM architecture and used stacked dependency for this. I want to call a method exist in ViewModel class from View class.
In this view class trigger method is `Widget build(BuildContext context)` So I am unable to get reference of ViewModel class.
Is there any way to achieve this.

For more details I have added my code for Stateless Widget:

```
class ECRView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values);
    return ViewModelBuilder<ECRViewModel>.reactive(
      onModelReady: (model)  {
        model.init(context);
      },
      builder: (context, model, child) => Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(AppSize.extraSmall),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: screenSize.width,
              height: 1.5,
              color: Colors.black12,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: screenSize.height * .02,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      viewModelBuilder: () => ECRViewModel(),
    );
  }

  //Trigger ECR Model Method
  getTriggered(){

    //From here I want to call
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work on your case, if you want to use the model on widgets

```
class _MyWidget extends ViewModelWidget<NameViewModel> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, NameViewModelmodel model) {
   //can call model
     return //some code
  }
}
```

This is not the best option for stacked architecture

```
class _MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final NameViewModelmodel model;

  const _MyWidget({Key key, this.model}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  __MyWidgetState createState() => __MyWidgetState();
}

class __MyWidgetState extends State<_MyWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: As I said I want to access this NameViewModelmodel object outside "build(BuildContext context, NameViewModelmodel model)" . How I can access it?

Comment: If its a refactored widget and the main parent wrap widget.. You can just pass the NameViewModelmodel as an constructor but this is not best way to do on stacked architecture